# HtmlGenericControl("a") vs. HtmlAnchor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, performance

I was looking into why one of my applications was running quite slowly.  The application generates and displays a grid and populates it with work tasks (rendered as table cells).  Inside each task there is an `<a href="...` which brings up some more info about the task.

As this is all built up dynamically from the codebehind, I've used `HTMLTableRows/Cells` to create the rows and cells, then used the `Controls` properties to add `HTMLAnchors`.  Whenever I'm setting attributes I've used `HTMLAnchor.HRef`, `HTMLTableCell.ColSpan`, etc.

I noticed that if I use the generic `HTMLGenericControl` and then use its `Attributes` collection, e.g.

```
HTMLGenericControl a = new HTMLGenericControl("a");
a.Attributes["href"] = task.getLink();
```

it runs significantly quicker than what I would have thought is the preferred way of doing the same thing:

```
HtmlAnchor a = new HTMLAnchor;
a.HRef = task.getLink();
```

Does anyone have any explanation for where this apparent extra 'overhead' comes from?

**EDIT**

In case anyone is confused by my explanation, I posted another question for the same project, which has a [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278562).

Comment: What do you mean by slow?  Does it take the browser a while to render the HTML? Or does it take a while to generate the HTML?  In your Web.Config in the system.web section, add the following `<trace enabled="true" localOnly="true" requestLimit="1000" pageOutput="true"/>` and you can see exactly where time is being spent

Comment: @s_hewitt That's really useful thanks.  It looks like the biggest time delays are between the Page Load begin & end, and the Render begin & end.  When I use the GenericControl approach the time is almost halved.

Comment: How does the total time for processing the page compare to rendering?  For example, if the total time in the trace is 1 second, but the page takes 5 seconds to load in the browser - then the transfer of the page is slow, or the rendering is slow.

Comment: @S_hewitt Bear with me - I'll have to get back to work to test this!  Will keep this question updated.

Comment: I can't answer why it's exactly slower but my thought is that the lowest common denominator will always be faster in terms of controls; that is, pure HTML will be faster than an ASP.NET control. In the same way, the HTMLAnchor is probably sub-classed from one or many base control classes (which adds overhead). But the generic control *probably* just uses HTML writer to render the tag you want and attributes you specify, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 5):

@subkamran I had the same thought, but after looking it up, actually both `HTMLAnchor` and `HTMLGenericControl` are sub-classed from the same parent: `HTMLContainerControl`.  One significant difference is that [HTMLAnchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx) implements the `IPostBackEventHandler` to handle the "ServerClick" event.  This surely adds something to the slowness ...